# Example of a non-surjective function $f:A\to B$ with $H\subseteq B$ such that $f(f^{-1}(H)) \neq H$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, functions

Example of a non-surjective function $f:A\to B$ with $H\subseteq B$ such that $f(f^{-1}(H)) \neq H$.
As the title says, I need a function that has this property.

Comment: Did you mean $f(f^{-1}(H))$? $f(H)$ isn't defined.

Comment: ...or perhaps $\;H\subset A\;$ ...?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ on the reals with $H=(-\infty,0)$...

Comment: Yeah, meant to have $f(f^{-1}(H))$ Can be any domain and codomain but it needs this property. Can't figure out an actual function that works.

Comment: Any non-surjective function and $H = B$.

Comment: I think the example by Daniel is the simplest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal examples are best! Consider the inclusion $f : \{0\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}.$ Then $f$ is not surjective. Now let $H = \{0,1\}.$ Then $f^{-1}(H) = \{0\},$ so $f(f^{-1}(H)) = \{0\}.$

Now, if you want a SUPER-minimal example...

Consider the empty function $f : \emptyset \rightarrow \{0\}.$ Then $f$ is not surjective. Now let $H = \{0\}.$ Then $f^{-1}(H) = \emptyset,$ so $f(f^{-1}(H)) = \emptyset.$

Comment: Haha the second $f$ is nice ^^

Answer (score 5):

Let $f: A \to B$ be non surjective. Chose $$\emptyset \neq H\subset B\setminus f(A)$$
Then $f^{-1}(H) \subset f^{-1}(B \setminus f(A)) = \emptyset$ and thus
$$f(f^{-1}(H)) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset \neq H$$

---

**Remark:** $H \cap B\setminus f(A) \neq \emptyset$ suffices already, and I think it is even equivalent to. But proof of that should be quite elementary...